# CONVERTING hierarchical data to ANT design Controlled Tree Format for loading the tree in UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, data-structures

Thanks for looking into this,I have an API response which needs to be converted to ANT design object format for controlled tree structure.I tried several ways of converting it to the desired format but keeps failing one way or the other.

```
`{
  "list": [
    {
      "obj": {
        "_type": "Asset",
        "name": "abc Logistics",
        "_id": 1957,
        "has": [
          {
            "_type": "Asset",
            "name": "New Asia Fleet",
            "_id": 1958,
            "has": [
              {
                "_type": "Asset",
                "name": "Dib Vivek Express",
                "_id": 1962,
                "has": [
                  {
                    "_type": "Asset",
                    "name": "S.E.Rail Carriage",
                    "_id": 1967,
                    "has": [
                      {
                        "_type": "Asset",
                        "name": "Engine 2398",
                        "_id": 19,
                        "AssetId": "89c5f2f4-fbfc-4689-9aa1-e04d03d39bbf"
                      }
                    ],
                    "AssetId": "056b61b4-18d7-4b3e-bf1c-e57c2d74bab3"
                  }
                ],
                "AssetId": "df03b1b4-800e-4726-9ff3-ca2619b39bc3"
              },
              {
                "_type": "Asset",
                "name": "Hanhen Train",
                "_id": 1961,
                "has": [
                  {
                    "_type": "Asset",
                    "name": "Chinese Carriage",
                    "_id": 1968,
                    "has": [
                      {
                        "_type": "Asset",
                        "name": "Engine 879",
                        "_id": 81,
                        "AssetId": "fff6c902-8a4e-43eb-ab11-2c12b6d259c7"
                      }
                    ],
                    "AssetId": "49a56d61-8052-4150-95de-79ac7ade9d1c"
                  }
                ],
                "AssetId": "a5f53465-2dbc-4767-9682-fa8b84300fe5"
              }
            ],
            "AssetId": "df87ac48-0ab5-4004-8288-bd8fa112ee05"
          },
          {
            "_type": "Asset",
            "name": "US Fleet",
            "_id": 1853,
            "has": [
              {
                "_type": "Asset",
                "name": "Test1",
                "_id": 76,
                "has": [
                  {
                    "_type": "Asset",
                    "name": "HT3363-1002",
                    "_id": 4,
                    "AssetId": "c6ba85ac-604c-417e-8726-c9afb0059657"
                  },
                  {
                    "_type": "Asset",
                    "name": "Test1Engine",
                    "_id": 79,
                    "AssetId": "c73b2933-ddf1-4490-bf11-435b74409f2a"
                  }
                ],
                "AssetId": "b3702890-4614-4946-b13f-0bd3c20931cb"
              },
              {
                "_type": "Asset",
                "name": "Test",
                "_id": 75,
                "has": [
                  {
                    "_type": "Asset",
                    "name": "TestENGINE",
                    "_id": 80,
                    "AssetId": "8e175d57-2e91-40fb-b704-cdb38ddbd0b1"
                  }
                ],
                "AssetId": "bf0a2315-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836"
              }
            ],
            "AssetId": "f93132d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe"
          }
        ],
        "AssetId": "c49c98fe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34"
      }
    }
  ]
}`
```

and

```
`const treeData: DataNode[] = [
  {
    title: "abc Logistics",
    key: "c49c98fe-3a2b-47e7-b7e9-e2e090ca0d34",
    children: [
      {
        title: "New Asia Fleet",
        key: "df87ac48-0ab5-4004-8288-bd8fa112ee05",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Hangzhou-Fuzhou-Shenzhen Train",
            key: "a5f53465-2dbc-4767-9682-fa8b84300fe5",
            children: [
              {
                title: "Chinese Carriage",
                key: "49a56d61-8052-4150-95de-79ac7ade9d1c",
                children: [
                  {
                    title: "Engine 879",
                    key: "fff6c902-8a4e-43eb-ab11-2c12b6d259c7"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "Dib Vivek Express",
            key: "df03b1b4-800e-4726-9ff3-ca2619b39bc3",
            children: [
              {
                title: "S.E.Rail Carriage",
                key: "056b61b4-18d7-4b3e-bf1c-e57c2d74bab3",
                children: [
                  {
                    title: "Engine 2398",
                    key: "89c5f2f4-fbfc-4689-9aa1-e04d03d39bbf"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "US Fleet",
        key: "f93132d9-05b8-4293-af55-2ee4617c6ffe",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Resolute",
            key: "b3702890-4614-4946-b13f-0bd3c20931cb",
            children: [
              {
                title: "HT3363-1002",
                key: "c6ba85ac-604c-417e-8726-c9afb0059657",
              },
              {
                title: "ResoluteEngine",
                key: "c73b2933-ddf1-4490-bf11-435b74409f2a",
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "Makruzz",
            key: "bf0a2315-b76c-426c-a272-6485359c5836",
            children: [
              {
                title: "MakruzzENGINE",
                key: "8e175d57-2e91-40fb-b704-cdb38ddbd0b1",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];`
```

I tried mapping through the api response and creating a new object to transform into the desired format.
But was stuck into recursive looping of childrens.Could Anyone help with How to convert it into desired format?